# Reconnect net.socket nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am new to node.js and would like to connect to a TCP socket. For this I am using the net module.

My idea was to wrap the connect sequence into a function then on the 'close' event, attempt a reconnection. Not that easy apparently.

```
function conn() {

    client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP, function() {
        startSequence();
    })
}

client.on('close', function(e) {
    log('info','Connection closed! -> ' + e)
    client.destroy();
    setTimeout(conn(),1000);
});
```

So when the remote host is closed, I see my logs comming through, howere what seems to be happening is that as soons as the remote host comes online ALL the previous attempts start to get processed - if that makes sense. If you look at client.connect, there is a function called startSequence that sends some data that "iniates" the connection from the remote server side. When the server goes offline and I start reconnecting all the failed attempts from before seem to have been buffered and are all sent together when the server goes online.

I have tried the code from this Stackoverflow link as well to no avail ([Nodejs - getting client socket to try again after 5 sec time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981040/nodejs-getting-client-socket-to-try-again-after-5-sec-time-out))

```
client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP, function() {
    pmsStartSequence();
})


// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function(e) {
    log('debug','connection  closed -> ' + e)
    client.setTimeout(10000, function() {
        log('debug', 'trying to reconnect')
        client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP, function() {
            pmsStartSequence();
        })
    })
});
```

Is there any advice on how I can reconnect a socket after failure?

Comment: Better way for client side to reconnect to the server after connection failure you could use below approach: 
var io = require('socket.io-client')var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {reconnect: true});

Comment: @Shrawan socket.io and socket.net are two different frameworks. For Node.js, you use socket.net

Answer (score 17):

Inspired from the other solutions, I wrote this, it's tested, it works ! 
It will keep on trying every 5 sec, until connection is made, works if it looses connection too.

```
/* Client connection */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

const client = new net.Socket()
var intervalConnect = false;

function connect() {
    client.connect({
        port: 1338,
        host: '127.0.0.1'
    })
}

function launchIntervalConnect() {
    if(false != intervalConnect) return
    intervalConnect = setInterval(connect, 5000)
}

function clearIntervalConnect() {
    if(false == intervalConnect) return
    clearInterval(intervalConnect)
    intervalConnect = false
}

client.on('connect', () => {
    clearIntervalConnect()
    logger('connected to server', 'TCP')
    client.write('CLIENT connected');
})

client.on('error', (err) => {
    logger(err.code, 'TCP ERROR')
    launchIntervalConnect()
})
client.on('close', launchIntervalConnect)
client.on('end', launchIntervalConnect)

connect()
```

Comment: I noticed that if I wanted to call `client.destroy()`, it will trigger `launchIntervalConnect` again and prevent the connection being destroyed. Any idea how to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Figured out a work around: `client.removeAllListeners()` followed by `client.destroy()`.

Comment: Thanks this is helping me a lot

Comment: This works perfectly! Honestly speaking, it should be the top answer. Handles it elegantly.

Comment: you can change this line  `if(false != intervalConnect) return`  to `if(intervalConnect) return`

Answer (score 16):

The problem is where you set the on-connect callback.

[The doc of socket.connect()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_port_host_connectlistener) says:

> connectListener ... will be added as a listener for the 'connect' event once.

By setting it in socket.connect() calls, every time you try reconnecting, one more listener (a one-time one), which calls startSequence(), is attached to that socket. Those listeners will not be fired until reconnection successes, so you got all of them triggered at the same time on a single connect.

One possible solution is separating the connect listener from socket.connect() calls.

```
client.on('connect', function() {
    pmsStartSequence();
});

client.on('close', function(e) {
    client.setTimeout(10000, function() {
        client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP);
    })
});

client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP);
```

Comment: This is a key point because not only does the close even not remove listeners, calling .end(), or even .destroy() will not remove the listeners either. So when you connect again, you get duplicate events. ebs's solution is elegant, but you can call .removeAllListeners() on the close event, and then re-add them when you re-connect.

Comment: yes separating the functions will solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
var parentHOST = '192.168.2.66';
var parentPORT = 9735;

var net = require('net');
var S = require('string');
var parentClient = new net.Socket();
var parentActive = false;

var startParentClient = function () {
    parentClient = new net.Socket();
    parentActive = false;

    parentClient.connect(parentPORT, parentHOST, function() {
      console.log('Connected ' + cluster.worker.id + ' to parent server: ' + parentHOST + ':' + parentPORT);
      parentActive = true;
    });

    parentClient.on('error', function() {
      parentActive = false;
      console.log('Parent connection error');
    });

    parentClient.on('close', function() {
      parentActive = false;
      console.log('parent connection closed');
      setTimeout(startParentClient(), 4000);
    });
  }
```

If is necessary connect:

```
  if (!S(parentHOST).isEmpty() && !S(parentPORT).isEmpty()) {
    startParentClient();
  }
```

Comment: just: setTimeout(startParentClient(), 4000);

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned multiple times in the comments, you need to use `.removeAllListeners()` before trying to reconnect your client to the server in order to avoid having multiple listeners on the same event.

The code below should do the trick

*Note that I try to reconnect the client after the `close` and `end` events because these two events can be fired in different orders after closing a connection*

```
const net = require("net")

let client = new net.Socket()

function connect() {
    console.log("new client")
    client.connect(
        1337,
        "127.0.0.1",
        () => {
            console.log("Connected")
            client.write("Hello, server! Love, Client.")
        }
    )

    client.on("data", data => {
        console.log("Received: " + data)
    })

    client.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Connection closed")
        reconnect()
    })

    client.on("end", () => {
        console.log("Connection ended")
        reconnect()
    })

    client.on("error", console.error)
}

// function that reconnect the client to the server
reconnect = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.removeAllListeners() // the important line that enables you to reopen a connection
        connect()
    }, 1000)
}

connect()
```

Comment: This answer is clean and simple, but sometimes end and close get called back to back for a single disconnect. Some of the other answers below that are inspired from this one seem to work better

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to achieve reconnection with node.js. I am not a Javascript expert so I guess it can be improved but it nevertheless works fine for me.
I hope this could help.
Best.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
// SocketClient                                                   //
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
var net = require('net');

var SocketClient = function(host, port, data_handler, attempt)
{
    var node_client;
    var attempt_index = (attempt ? attempt : 1);

    this.m_node_client = new net.Socket();
    node_client = this.m_node_client;
    this.m_node_client.on('close', function()
    {
        var new_wrapper = new SocketClient(host, port, data_handler, attempt_index + 1);

        node_client.destroy();
        new_wrapper.start();
    });
    this.m_node_client.on('data', data_handler);
    this.m_node_client.on('error', function(data)
    {
        console.log("Error");
    });
    this.start = function()
    {
        this.m_node_client.connect(port, host, function()
        {
            console.log('Connected ' + attempt_index);
        });
    };
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
// Test                                                           //
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
var test_handler = function(data)
{
    console.log('TestHandler[' + data + ']');
};
var wrapper = new SocketClient('127.0.0.1', 4000, test_handler);

wrapper.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried re-using the same socket connection, by using this:

```
const s = net.createConnection({port});

s.once('end', () => {
    s.connect({port}, () => {

    });
});
```

that didn't work, from the server-side's perspective. If the client connection closes, it seems like a best practice to create a new connection:

```
const s = net.createConnection({port});

s.once('end', () => {
    // create a new connection here
    s = net.createConnection(...);
});
```

sad but true lulz.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://gist.github.com/nfacciolo/dbac4aa5852008f6c61e5602a5e34513):

```
//
// Simple example of using net.Socket but here we capture the
// right events and attempt to re-establish the connection when
// is is closed either because of an error establishing a
// connection or when the server closes the connection.
//

// Requires
const net = require('net');

// Create socket
const port = 5555;
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const timeout = 1000;
let retrying = false;

// Functions to handle socket events
function makeConnection () {
    socket.connect(port, host);
}
function connectEventHandler() {
    console.log('connected');
    retrying = false;
}
function dataEventHandler() {
    console.log('data');
}
function endEventHandler() {
    // console.log('end');
}
function timeoutEventHandler() {
    // console.log('timeout');
}
function drainEventHandler() {
    // console.log('drain');
}
function errorEventHandler() {
    // console.log('error');
}
function closeEventHandler () {
    // console.log('close');
    if (!retrying) {
        retrying = true;
        console.log('Reconnecting...');
    }
    setTimeout(makeConnection, timeout);
}

// Create socket and bind callbacks
let socket = new net.Socket();
socket.on('connect', connectEventHandler);
socket.on('data',    dataEventHandler);
socket.on('end',     endEventHandler);
socket.on('timeout', timeoutEventHandler);
socket.on('drain',   drainEventHandler);
socket.on('error',   errorEventHandler);
socket.on('close',   closeEventHandler);

// Connect
console.log('Connecting to ' + host + ':' + port + '...');
makeConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createServer() {
  const client = new net.Socket();

  client.connect(HOST_PORT, HOST_IP, function() {
    console.log("Connected");
    state = 1 - state;
    client.write(state.toString());
  });

  client.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log("Received: " + data);
    //client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
  });

  client.on("close", function() {
    console.log("Connection closed");
    //client.connect()
    setTimeout(createServer, 2000);
  });
}

createServer();
```

Comment: please add some text explaining how your solution works